# STM32G474 Bizarre ADC Issue - Values starting jumping periodically some time after startup

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, adc, dma, stm32cubeide

I'm at my wits end trying to debug an STM32 ADC issue. I'm using 9 channels of ADC4 to read cell voltages from op amps, instrumentation amps, and a few other voltages through dividers. These circuits have been in use on production boards using the STM32G070. There are a few other peripheral changes around the board but everything that interacts with the ADC is the same.

The issue is as follows: While I'm monitoring my ADC buffer via live expressions the values all seem normal and correct. I've verified them with a meter/scope. After some period of time, they will start to "jump." They periodically jump by a few hundred then return back to their nominal value. The only way to fix this is to restart the debugger.

The external voltage reference and MCU supply are both stable and correct. I'm not sure what else to check but would love some suggestions.

My code uses DMA. I will post screenshots of the IOC setup below. I'm using the ADC calibration function and essentially the same code as was used successfully on the G070.

Here are the snippets of code that deal with the ADC's

```
// Calibrate ADCs
  if (HAL_ADCEx_Calibration_Start(&hadc4,LL_ADC_SINGLE_ENDED) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  // Start ADCs
  __HAL_ADC_ENABLE_IT(&hadc4, ADC_IT_OVR);
  if (HAL_ADC_Start_DMA(&hadc4, (uint32_t *)&adc_buf, ADC_BUF_LEN) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
```

```
void HAL_ADC_ConvCpltCallback(ADC_HandleTypeDef *hadc4)
{
  adc_new_data_flag = 1;
  adc_conv_period = time-last_adc_conv_time;
  //adc_conv_freq = 1000/adc_conv_period;
  last_adc_conv_time = time;

}
```

Any thoughts? I would greatly appreciate some help.

EDIT:

I've added an image of the ADC buffer data. It appears to be pulsing around every 380ms. I'm also going to link to the Excel file containing the data and chart.

It certainly seems like a hardware issue but nothing is showing up on the scope.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mubIf5-qkqeYzMgEoc5ym9TvHDc9_zzc?usp=sharing

[image: Config Screenshot 1]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Values jumping around sounds like it could be noise on your signal. Have you looked at your signal with an oscilloscope when the value is jumping?

Comment: Please show an example of your readings jumping, either as a table or values or in a graph with numbered axes.

Comment: I have looked at the signals with the scope. The are correct and not jumping going in to the ADC. I'm setting up SWV to log the raw ADC values and will post when I have those.

Comment: @brhans I've added a link to an Excel file with the ADC buffer data and adding a photo of the graphed data. Thanks!